# Microsoft graph call does not return the group's preferred language

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-graph-api

I am running this call to get the group details.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/<group-id>
```

It returns the group details but the preferredLanguage is null. Even though I set the preferred language of the group in office 365 portal.

This looks like a bug in the API.

Comment: Yup - I was able to reproduce this.  Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Please consider this for internal users(AD users) as well as guest users(MS Users)

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT: did you get a resolution on this bug? If so, would you add an answer?

Comment: This is still not supported

Comment: 6 years later, the preferredLanguage is still null :-|